# Django how to use a ModelChoiceField in a formset_factory

Tags: django, forms, formset

I am trying to use a modelchoicefield from the form in a formset_factory but i dont understand the error and don't know how to solve it.

(edit added the models.py)
models.py

```
class Order(Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)
    fee = ForeignKey(Fee, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)
    route = ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)
    price_rate = ForeignKey(PriceRate, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)
    pallet_amount = IntegerField()
    status = BooleanField()
    postal_code = CharField(max_length=6)
    city = CharField(max_length=255)
    street = CharField(max_length=255)
    delivery_from = DateTimeField()
    delivery_until = DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted_at = DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def routecreate_view(request):
    orderformset = formset_factory(OrdersRouteForm, can_delete=False, extra=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RouteForm(request.POST)
        formset = orderformset(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required

            messages.success(request,
                             "You succesfully created an route.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('planner.dashboard'))
    else:
        form = RouteForm()
        formset = orderformset()
    return render(request, 'planner/route.html', {'form': form, 'formset': formset})
```

forms.py

```
class OrdersRouteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    route = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Order.objects.filter(status=1, delivery_until__gte=datetime.datetime.now(), deleted_at=None),
        label='Order')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ("route",)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrdersRouteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control m-2'

            self.fields['route'].label_from_instance = self.label_from_instance

    @staticmethod
    def label_from_instance(obj):
        return "pallets: %s, %s, %s, %s" % (obj.pallet_amount, obj.street, obj.city, obj.postal_code)
```

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block base %}
    <div class="container rounded bg-white mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 border-right mx-auto">
                planner//route
                <div class="p-3 py-5">
                    <form id="form-container" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form }}
                        {{ formset }}
                        <button id="add-form" type="button">Add Another Bird</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger profile-button mt-3" onclick="window.history.back()">Cancel
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary float-end mt-3" type="submit">Order</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

error:

```
Cannot assign "<Order: Order object (2)>": "Order.route" must be a "Route" instance.
```

The error occurs when i fill the formset with request.POST and then try to send the formset to the template.

I have tried an inlineformset and modelformset and didnt get it to work. ANY solution is welcome.

Comment: Can you share the models for the same

Comment: @rahul.m i've added the related model as requested.

Comment: There is a problem with `label_from_instance`. Static method but with a obj param ? you have to call with `OrdersRouteForm.label_from_instance(XXX)` for beginning. But you don't have access to Order object at this time. You need to create firstly your Routes object and in your view, you set the Order attach to each instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with the modelform. I removed this from the code:

```
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ("route",)
```

I don't understand why this caused the problem and if anyone knows and can explain it please feel free to do so.

hope it helps anyone else with this problem.